# Edit variables with command discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, database, discord, discord.js, command

I'm working on a discord.js v13 bot, and I want to make a command that add the channel Id where the command executed in an existing variable and, another command that works only with the channels in the variable

This is the variable

```
const ch = ["1068584484473143386","1068570010756337705","","","",]
```

The command that works with the channels stored

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {

if(message.author.bot) return;

if(ch.includes(message.channel.id)) {

const prompt = message.content

      message.channel.sendTyping(60)

const answer = await ask(prompt); 

message.channel.send(answer); 

}});
```

Edit : I used array.push() in an command but it didn't work it didn't do anything

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {

   if (message.content === '..auto-on') {

    

       
if(!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    message.channel.reply("**You don't have permissions**")};
  
       

        

 ch.push(`${message.channel.id}`)

       message.channel.reply(`**Added ${message.channel} to auto-reply**`);

       

       }});
```

Edit 2 : it worked but it get reset after restarting

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to insert a new channel Id to an existing array, you can do that using the `Array.push()` method.

Example:

```js
const arrayofItems = ["Flour", "Milk", "Sugar"]

console.log(arrayofItems) // ["Flour", "Milk", "Sugar"]

arrayofItems.push("Coffee")

console.log(arrayofItems) // ["Flour", "Milk", "Sugar", "Coffee"]
```

Make sure to learn the basics of JS before starting out with libraries such as Discord.JS.

Comment: But it get reset after restarting

Comment: If you don't want it to reset use a database like SQL or MongoDB.